# Who is it referring to in this sentence? お前のこと護ろうとして、余計に傷つけて

Tags: meaning

> 鈴木を、壊しちゃった… なのに、お前のこと護ろうとして、余計に傷つけて
> I broke Suzuki... Nevertheless, in an effort to protect you

The second sentence, who does it refer to?

Context: A girl (Lisa) says those lines to her boyfriend. Previously she had been talking with his ex-girlfriend (Susuki), who had entered into a deep depression because the boy had chosen Lisa. Lisa tries to comfort Suzuki but ends up hurting her more. At the same time Lisa was worried because Suzuki kept saying that she will win him back, to which Lisa says that she will always be with the boy, so that's impossible.

My question: In the second sentence who was Lisa protecting? The boy (making it clear he's hers) or Susuki (who she wanted to console and make amends with her). She's talking to the boy when she says that.

Comment: More context: Previously when both girls were talking Susuki says she might break her head to make the boy feel pity, that way he'll choose her. Instead, after that Lisa almost cripples her arm as compensation for taking the boy. My question: When she almost cripples her arm, who is she protecting according to this sentence? her boyfriend (making it clear he's hers) or Suzuki (as she had said she wanted to compensate her for taking him and to make amends).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Lisa is saying these lines to the boy, then お前 must be referring to that boy. It's simply because お前 is always a second-person pronoun (="you"). The third line also seems to be saying "I ended up hurting *you* (=the boy)".

Comment: 2 questions. First, how would you translate the the whole paragraph? And second, you sure the third line refers to the boy? Because it sure seems that Lise (the one that almost breaks her head) has it worse than him.

Comment: I'm certain that お前 refers to "you", but for others, the context is still lacking. Is Lisa a kind of character who may well say お前 to her boyfriend? And I felt 「鈴木を壊した、なのに鈴木を傷つけた」 ("I broke Suzuki, *but* I hurt Suzuki") doesn't make much sense to me. On the other hand 「鈴木を壊した、なのにお前を傷つけた」 may make sense depending on the story. (i.e., "I broke Suzuki in order to protect you, but it ended up hurting you")

Comment: The girls love each other (best friends), they don't want to hurt each other and suffer greatly if they do. They fought for one boy because they fell in love and in the end one girl must suffer. The boy suffers too because that ex-girlfriend (Susuki) was also his fiancee. The boy and Lise leave the country and it hurts him that Susuki has been broken. Knowing that, how would you translate the whole paragraph?

Comment: By any chance, isn't the last 傷つけて actually 傷ついて? Then everything fits the context you described. "(Sadly,) I broke Suzuki. But she still wanted to protect you, and that ended up hurting herself all the more."

Comment: It says 余計に傷つけて

Comment: Last 2 things. First, imagine there's no context how would you translate the paragraph?

Comment: A safe translation would be "Trying to protect you resulted in more pain..." I'm still unsure (1) who was trying to "protect" him (was it really Lisa?), and (2) whose pain she was talking about.

Comment: Basically, what strikes you as most likely about (1) and (2)

Comment: (1) Either Lisa or Suzuki. (2) Either Haruki's pain or Suzuki's pain. It depends on the story line (who was defending who?), and unfortunately your quote did not help.